# Ubuntu 17.10: One of the two DisplayPort monitors connected to my PC does not wake up from suspend

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management, 17.10

If I set "Blank screen" in "Power Saving" settings to anything other than "Never":

[image: Ubuntu Power Saving - Blank Screen]

When the displays go blank and I come back the day after to use my PC, one of the displays remains blank and I have to restart the computer to make it work again.

Here are the display settings:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (0x24) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
    Identifier: 0x21
    Timestamp:  221264
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  2560x1440 (0x24) 312.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.45KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.91Hz
XWAYLAND1 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (0x24) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
    Identifier: 0x23
    Timestamp:  221264
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  2560x1440 (0x24) 312.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.45KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.91Hz
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't know how you can fix it but I do have an idea for a workaround that at least would prevent the need for a system reset. Mind you, this will only work if you are able to start a terminal on the monitor that does wakes up.

Let say the monitor XWAYLAND1 remains asleep.
Force it off and the on again by

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --off
xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --left-of XWAYLAND0 --auto
```